# What is called when removing a view from its superview?

Tags: objective-c, view, subview, superview

Imagine I have a view controller called `blueView` and another called `greenView`. I then add `greenView.view` as a subview of `blueView.view`. Now suppose that after some user interaction, I'd like to remove `greenView.view` from `blueView.view` using:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview]
```

What is actually happening here? Is `blueView.view` ever redrawn? I thought the `viewDidLoad` method might be called, however after putting an `NSLog` messge in `viewDidLoad`, it was never called after removing the subview. Any clarification as to what is actually happening when you remove a subview from its superview would be much appreciated.

Comment: viewDidLoad is a UIViewController method, not a UIView method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a view controller is meant to manage an entire view hierarchy at once; you shouldn't have two view controllers (other than container controllers like UINavigationController) active at the same time. See [this SO question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5691226/643383) to get a better understanding on this important point. So, the particular situation you describe shouldn't come up. (Aside: people often confuse views and view controllers, so it's not helpful to give your view controllers names ending in "-view", like "blueView." Call it "blueViewController" to help avoid confusion.)

Second, as @InsertWittyName points out, `-viewDidLoad` is a UIViewController method, not a UIView method. Taking that a step further, neither view controllers nor `-viewDidLoad` has any role in adding or removing subviews from a view. `-viewDidLoad` is called when the view controller's view is first created. It's basically just a way of deferring the view-related part of view controller initialization until after the view hierarchy has been created, so there's no reason that it'd be called again just because a subview was removed from the hierarchy.

Finally, exactly how a view removes itself from its superview is really an implementation detail -- it might call a private UIView method on the superview, or it might modify the superview's list of subviews directly, or something else. I don't see anything in the documentation that explicitly says that the superview will redraw itself after a subview has been removed, but in my experience the superview does indeed redraw itself. You can check this by putting a breakpoint on the `-drawRect` method of the superview.

Comment: I believe you know more than me, if I could i would delete my own answer, so yours can be accept. +1

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and complete explanation :)